# angular 2/4 breadcrumb for sidebar menu

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I want to implement breadcrumb for my sidebar menu. My menus are
Menu1
Menu2
  subMenu1
  subMenu2
.
.
.

after clicking Menu2 it just expands then clicking subMenu1 I want to show breadcrumb as Home > Menu2 > subMenu1
I want to implement it like - clicking on Home it should redirect to dashboard page. Menu2 should not be clickable (there is nothing, just expand menu). subMenu2 should be clickable.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but in case someone will have similar problem, I want to provide a solution for Angular 6+.
Not really an elegant one, but you should be able to do this with css and ng6-breadcrumbs.

**Note:** In this solution, subMenu2 will not be clickable, because you should NOT be able to navigate to the site page, which is already displayed.

## How to disable breadcrumbs in Angular 6+

**PHASE I - Prepare project:**

**1** - Create new project with routing:

```
  ng new breadcrumb-demo --routing
```

**2** -   Install bootstrap:

```
   npm install jquery --save
   npm install bootstrap --save 
   npm install ngx-bootstrap --save
```

**3** - Include bootstrap in **angular.json** (*"architect"* -> *"build"*):

```
    "styles": [ 
        "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css", 
        "src/styles.css" 
    ]


    "scripts": [ 
        "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
        "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    ]
```

**4** - Install ng6-breadcrumbs:

```
npm install --save ng6-breadcrumbs
```

**5** - Include ng6-breadcrumbs in your **app.module.ts**:

```
import {BreadcrumbsModule} from "ng6-breadcrumbs";
```

**Note:** Remeber to add BreadcrumbsModule in import section.

**PHASE II - Implementation:**

**1** - After adding all components you need + start page and error page, set your routing in **app-routing.module.ts**:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full'
},
{
    path: 'home',
    component: StartPageComponent,
    data: {
      breadcrumb: 'Home'//<--Breadcrumb label
    },
    children: [
    {
          path: 'menu1',
          component: Menu1Component,
          pathMatch: 'full',
          data: {
              breadcrumb: 'Menu1'//<--Breadcrumb label
          },
    },
    {
        path: 'menu2',
        component: Menu2Component,
        data: {
            breadcrumb: 'Menu2'//<--Breadcrumb label
        },
        children: [
        {
            path: '',
            redirectTo: '/home/menu2/submenu1',
            pathMatch: 'full',
        },
        {
            path: 'submenu1',
            component: Submenu1Component,
            data: {
                breadcrumb: 'Submenu1'//<--Breadcrumb label
            },
        },
        {
            path: 'submenu2',
            component: Submenu2Component,
            data: {
                breadcrumb: 'Submenu2'//<--Breadcrumb label
            },
        }
      ]
    },
  ]
},
{
    path: '**',
    component: ErrorPageComponent
}
];
```

**2** - Add to every component that has children routing tag in HTML:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**3** - In **app.component.html**, in place where you want your breadcrumbs, add:

```
<breadcrumb id="breadcrumbComponent" [allowBootstrap]="true"></breadcrumb>
```

**4** - Modify global **style.css** file, where you will disable 'Menu2' breadcrumb:

```
/* All not activated breadcrumbs style*/
#breadcrumbComponent .breadcrumb-item a{
  color: green;
}
/* Activated breadcrumbs style*/
#breadcrumbComponent .breadcrumb-item.active {
  color: blue
}
/* Breadcrumb with specific link */
#breadcrumbComponent .breadcrumb-item a[href="/home/menu2"]{
  color: red !important;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

**DONE :)**

Now you should see breadcrumb component on your page, and after entering link /home/menu2/submenu1, menu2 breadcrumb 'Menu2' should be red and NOT clickable ;)